# How to query ORDER by date DESC when you have two dates in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My calendar table has `start` and `end` column and they have the same data type which is `date`. Now I'm having trouble on how to query and select the data in `desc` order according to the date recorded in the `start` column. Does anyone know how does my query should be?
I only have this:
//code indentation

```
$query = "select * from calendar";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
                ...

}
```

EDIT:
The right query is

```
$query = "select * from calendar ORDER by start DESC";
```

Thanks to everyone who answered! :)

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY start DESC`?

Comment: i just did, and that works! :D thank you sir! i tried "order by start date desc" before, obviously it was wrong haha thank you sir! :) @Eihwaz

Comment: What do you mean by "The right query is"? That's the same as the original query in the question.

Comment: Instead of posting the correct query in your question you should mark one the answer that helped you as accepted.

Comment: ofcourse i will do that, stackoverflow said i should wait 7minutes so i'm waiting. and the i couldn't vote for the person who helped me because he helped me by commenting, but i will still accept those who have the same correct answer @Jester

Comment: @user6151429 that's okay, i didn't mean to give a negative connotation with my comment ;)

Comment: okay, sorry. @Jester

Comment: It's perfectly fine :) do take a look at Barmar's comment though. your edit just displays your old query, it doesn't order on `start`

Comment: oh, didn't notice that. lol thanks!! :) @Jester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does just doing a simple ORDER BY not work?

```
$query = "select * from calendar ORDER BY start DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "select * from calendar ORDER BY start DESC";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res) )
{
  // your code

}
```

I think this should work. You can use **ORDER BY**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select * from calendar ORDER BY date1, date2 DESC";
```

Mysql will first check for date1 if it is blank it will go for date2

Comment: not only if it's blank, it will order first on date1, and order again on date 2 for all values where date1 are equal. Also you have to add DESC behind the date1 as well.